# Updating SQL table with decimal values yields only 0s

Tags: sql, sql-server

On MSSQL: I am adding a column to a table

```
ALTER table
ADD x_column DECIMAL
```

Now, I perform a calculation using another column of the same table:

```
SELECT SELECT CAST(a_column AS decimal)/CAST (1000000000*0.1*12 AS decimal) FROM table
```

This yields the expected result:

```
+---+-----------------------+
¦ 1 ¦ 0.0000732950000000000 ¦
+---+-----------------------+
¦ 2 ¦ 0.0000016912500000000 ¦
+---+-----------------------+
¦ 3 ¦ 0.0005905541666666666 ¦
+---+-----------------------+
```

However, when I try to update the table with these values, all I get are zeroes:

```
UPDATE table
SET x_column = CAST(a_column AS DECIMAL)/CAST(1000000000*0.1*12 AS decimal)

 id   x_column
+---+-----------------------+
¦ 1 ¦ 0                     ¦
+---+-----------------------+
¦ 2 ¦ 0                     ¦
+---+-----------------------+
¦ 3 ¦ 0                     ¦
+---+-----------------------+
```

What I'd like is for the results of the above SELECT to be inserted into the column in the table.

Comment: What is the type of `x_column`?  My guess is that it is not big enough to represent the decimal places.

Comment: When you don't specify precision or scale for a `DECIMAL` it (annoyingly) defaults to `DECIMAL (38,0)`, which won't store ANY decimal places at all.  In your query you also don't specify any scale or precision, but this time SQL Server will box your result based on the fact you are dividing two decimals, and hence you get a result with scale. It looks like you actually need a large scale to store those numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to add the precision and scale on the [`DECIMAL` datatype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

**If not specified, the default scale is 0.**

When you add your column you should use:

```
ALTER table
ADD x_column DECIMAL(35, 19)
```

or something larger up to 38 digits.

Precision is how many digits your number would have, while the scale is the **number of digits after** the decimal point.

Answer (score 4):

You should add scale and precision to your columne declaration, if omitted it is 0

```
ALTER table ADD x_column DECIMAL(28,12)
```

Comment: Precision is the total number of digits to the left AND right of the decimal place, and defaults to 38.  Scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal place, and defaults to 0.  So you have the right approach, but the explanation is wrong.

Comment: Nitpick: default _scale_ is 0 (default precision is 18).